# C# Readonly function

Tags: c#

how do i make a Property in C# readonly ?

I tried to do the C# Property

```
  public string Title { get;  }
    public  abstract string? Html { get;  }
    public int RatingCount => UserEmail.Count;
    public decimal? AverageRating { get
    {
        decimal sum = UserEmail.Values.Sum();
        return RatingCount > 0 ? (sum / RatingCount) : null;
    }}
    private List<Comment> _comment { get; } = new();
    public IReadOnlyList<Comment> Comments => _comment.AsReadOnly();

    private readonly Dictionary<string, int> UserEmail = new();
    
    public Post(User user, string title)
    {
        uesr = user;
        Title = title;
    }
```

this is a descrption for what happend

Comment: Java is **not** C#. Tagging your C# question with Java is not something you should do.

Comment: "this is a descrption for what happend" is it invisible ink?

Comment: Your keyboard seems to have run out of ink, sadly. I can't see where the error is.
Can you quickly re-fill and get back to us?

Comment: You can make a property effectively read-only a couple of ways.  Once is to elide the getter: `public string MyProp { get; }`.  If you want to have that property set at all, you must either initialize it in the declaration (adding `="Some Value";`) to the end of the declaration, or initialize it in a constructor (preferable all constructors).  You can also declare the setter `private` (`public string MyProp { get; private set}`) in which case it can be set anywhere in the class's code, but not externally.  There's also `init` (`public string MyProp { get; init}`), allowing sets at init time

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Look at this example, I hope it solves your question:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly int _myField;

    public MyClass(int myField)
    {
        _myField = myField;
    }

    public int GetMyField()
    {
        return _myField;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't good answers

Comment: I think the code that I have put solves the issue, it does not need many words to explain it, what it wants is a very simple readOnly property.

Comment: @ELTeleco I don't see any property in your code.

Comment: @SomeBody I have not said it in my code :), and it is already solved and validated by the interesting one. Thanks for your comments.